# Could you simplify the highlighted parts of this short passage?

Tags: meaning-in-context

> They had taken the path through the trees and, *emerging from what had become a small wood*, they marvelled at the open land , as that morning they had marvelled at sunshine in February, misty though it was. *Nothing as tiresome as rain had spoiled their walk from the rail way station or their returning to it now*. *"I would have travelled a million miles for this afternoon." Miss Ceble summed up their outing* as they approached the first line of bungalows on the town's outskirts.

Could you simplify the highlighted parts of this short passage?

Comment: Welcome to ELL! To interpret (I take it that by *simplify* you might mean *to interpret those parts in a simple manner), it might be the best to provide more clues, especially the time the scene happened (was it in the morning, around noon, or in the afternoon?), and perhaps what they have been through (a jungle, an orchard, mangrove trees?). Also, it might be the best for our site to ask only one specific question in each post (so we can discuss each part at length). Lastly, it is advised to quote the source of the text.

Answer (score 2):

> emerging from what had become a small wood

This phrase implies either 1) they had been traveling through a large wood (forest) and had come to an area near the edge that had a smaller shape, so it would be described as a "small wood", or 2) (less likely) they were traveling in a wood that was at one point in the past was large, but was now small.

> Nothing as tiresome as rain had spoiled their walk from the rail way
>   station or their returning to it now.

This sentence is unclear. Here, rain is considered tiresome (causing you to be tired and/or bored, with a connotation of unpleasant and/or annoying). The sentence either means that 1) It was raining during their walk, but even tiresome rain had not spoiled it, or 2) nothing tiresome, including rain, had occurred to spoil their walk.

> "I would have travelled a million miles for this afternoon." Miss
>   Ceble summed up their outing

Most likely, it means Miss Ceble enjoyed their afternoon walk so much that (had she known how great it was going to be) she would have made a really large effort to experience it.